# vscode variable to read current line not selected text

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a configuration in launch.json and the configuration need the variable that has the text of current line.
How could i get the text of current line as variable.

For example, below will run only one test case that cursor is located if "${currentLineText}" variable was available.

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "robotframework-lsp",
            "name": "Robot: Selected Test",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "target": "${file}",
            "terminal": "integrated",
            "env": {},
            "args": ["-L", "DEBUG", "--pythonpath", "${workspaceFolder}", "-t", "${currentLineText}"]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you use the `${selectedText}` variable instead?  Select the line first yourself or make a prelaunchtask that selects the current line.

Comment: ${selectedText} shows selected text. if no text selected, this will be empty. I want to get the current line under the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) version 1.2.0 is a command variable named `currentLineText`

use it like `"${extension.commandvariable.currentLineText}"`